# Create JSON with wrapped name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

For example i have JSON like this

```
{
    "1":"12",
    "2":"13",
    "3":"14"
}
```

How can i wrap them like

```
"data":{
    "1":"12",
    "2":"13",
    "3":"14"
}
```

Any lib we can do this ?
Thank you a lots

Comment: how are you receiving that JSON? Or are you trying to return it from node, and want to pass it as `data`?

Comment: Please provide more context to show what it is you are trying to accomplish and why you are trying to accomplish it.  From what I see here there is no reason a library should be necessary for something like this.

Comment: No, just local json bro, i'm just play around with JSON types

Comment: what's the goal exactly? what do you want to do ? you already wrap that !!

Comment: Show some code please on what you have attempted

Comment: That’s not JSON. You can’t have a `”property”: value` pair outside of an object.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I see you are a somewhat newer user-- I always recommend new users visit [ask] for tips on forming questions in a way that best enables the community to provide assistance.  Unfortunately, your question was closed today.  This is because there was not enough context provided for your issue to be clearly understood, so a meaningful answer was challenging to provide.  @Snowmonkey provided an answer based on a guess-- that answer may be correct, but it is impossible to know.  You should aim to provide a [mcve] in all your posts.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const json = `{
  "1": "34.4",
  "dog":"Snoopy",
  "more": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
}`

const myObj = {
  data: JSON.parse(json)
}

console.log(myObj);
```

Simply that would do it. JSON is simply a string format, representing a javascript object. So within `myObj`, I can assign that to an object property *and parse that JSON string into an object*.

Comment: This does answer the question if we take the OP at their word that they are manipulating JSON and not misstating that they are actually using an object.  Also-- how did you answer after the question was already closed?

Comment: Thank for your answer, but why my question closed???? i mean, how can i put the name "data" wrap to my object?

Comment: [Nevermind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed).